# Purpose for setting replicator socket_options nodelay to true in CouchDb

Tags: couchdb

I am trying to get more info on what this setting does in CouchDb:

```
[replicator]
socket_options = [{keepalive, true}, {nodelay, false}]
```

What does `nodelay` do? What are the differences when it is set to true? I can't seem to find any information on setting in the CouchDb guide or in default.ini (which just says that 'Some socket options that might boost performance in some scenarios')

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in the erlang [docs](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/inet.html#setopts-2):

```
{nodelay, Boolean}(TCP/IP sockets)
If Boolean == true, the TCP_NODELAY option is turned on for the socket, which means that even small amounts of data will be sent immediately.
```